# Using Twigbridge in a Laravel 5.1 Package

Tags: laravel, twig

I'm trying to create a Laravel 5.1 package which uses `Twigbridge` instead of `.php` views. I can get normal `.php` views to display fine, but when I try to make use of `.twig` templates I'm only met with an error. Is it possible to use Twigbridge templates when creating views for a Laravel Package or we pretty much stuck with `blade` and `php`?

**Edit 1:** Loading a Twig template without extending anything works. It's when I start using `{% extends 'file' %}` that the error comes out.

I get this error

```
Error loading /virtual/laravel/packages/username/mypackage/src/Views/sample.twig:
Template "templates.master" is not defined () in
"/virtual/laravel/packages/username/mypackage/src/Views/sample.twig" at line 1.
```

My folders

```
username
    |_ mypackage
        |_ src
            |_ Controllers
                - SampleController.php
            |_ Views
                |_ templates
                        - master.twig
                - sample.twig
```

Twig template *sample.twig*

```
{% extends 'templates.master' %}

{% block content %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}
```

My *templates/master.twig* file has `{% block content %} Hello World {% endblock %}` in it.

My *composer.json*

```
{
    "name": "username/mypackage",
    "description": "",
    "license": "MIT",
    "keywords": ["laravel"],
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "username",
            "email": "username@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "rcrowe/twigbridge": "0.7.x"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

My Service Provider (simplified)

```
<?php namespace Username\MyPackage;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class MyPackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {   
        // Route
        include __DIR__.'/routes.php';
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // This line works fine for normal .php views but for some reason not for .twig views
        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/Views', 'mypackage');

        // Providers
        $this->app->register('TwigBridge\ServiceProvider');

        // Aliases
        $loader = \Illuminate\Foundation\AliasLoader::getInstance();
        $loader->alias('Twig', 'TwigBridge\Facade\Twig');

        $this->app['mypackage'] = $this->app->share(function($app) {
            return new MyPackage;
        });
    }

    /**
    * Register a view file namespace.
    *
    * @param  string  $namespace
    * @param  string  $path
    * @return void
    */
    protected function loadViewsFrom($path, $namespace)  
    {
        if (is_dir($appPath = $this->app->basePath().'/resources/views/vendor/'.$namespace)) {
            $this->app['view']->addNamespace($namespace, $appPath);
        }
        $this->app['view']->addNamespace($namespace, $path);
    }
    /*
    */

}
```

Controller is pretty basic

```
<?php namespace Username\MyPackage\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class SampleController extends Controller {

    public function sample() {
        return view('mypackage::sample');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I found out the answer was to reference the package. So `{% extends 'folder.file' %}` becomes `{% extends 'packagename::folder/file' %}`.

That successfully loads the file but it does not answer how to get functions like `{{ form_text() }}` to work. Since I'm using `rcrowe/twigbridge` is there any way to get the functions to work?

Comment: I had to copy the `twigbridge.php` config file into the Laravel config directory, from the TwigBridge vendor package, and uncommect the Form and Html extensions.

If there's a better way of extending the package config without copying the whole file, I'd be happy to hear it :)

Comment: You can run `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="TwigBridge\ServiceProvider"` which basically copies the `twigbride.php` file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try a `{% extends 'templates/master.twig' %}` in simple.twig instead of `{% extends 'templates.master' %}` .

Comment: This is because your template (master.twig) is in a very low folder than its child file (simple.twig)